# How to disable "SAVE" button until all fields are completed

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a form which takes the user's credit card information, all this is being validated by an e-commerce API. I have other fields in the form such as name, address. I am able to validate the names and address, but since the input of the credit card information is being validated by back-end. Is their a way for me to disable the button until all fields are completed?

```
<div class="medium-6 columns" *ngIf="!isLoading else updateLoading">
     <button class="saves" (click)="onSave()" aria-label="Save user info" 
     [disabled]="!editForm.valid">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using reactive forms? If so you can ping the reactive forms to know it's status i.e. valid or invalid and concequently  hide / show the button. Alternatively you can fire a function on each Fields keypress event to detect the status of the form field if you don't prefer the idea of pinging your reactive form

Comment: Do you mean all required fields are entered? then your code is correct provided `editForm` is the name of the FormGroup in your html. , You can also check `editForm.invalid` it will be true if there are any required fields which are empty

Comment: yes I am using reactive form

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Reactive Forms, you would want to set your fields to required by using the `Validators.required` validator ([see docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#required)). Once you have all of the required fields set using a validator, you would watch for the form groups valid. The could would look something like this below.

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
   ...
   <div class="medium-6 columns" *ngIf="!isLoading else updateLoading">
      <button class="saves" (click)="onSave()" aria-label="Save user info" 
      [disabled]="editForm.invalid">Save</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how can I make the button color change? It seems that it wont change color since validation doesn't work for credit cards.

Comment: You can use `(ngClass)="{invalid: editForm.invalid}"` https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 0):

Your code to disable seems to be correct.

However, please check if `editForm.valid` is `boolean`. It helps to debug if you have a simple boolean instead of boolean as a property of an object.